# Triggering OAuth2 flow in .NET Core 6 for stateless microservices with JWT bearer tokens, without cookie sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, openid-connect

I have a .NET Core 6 API Gateway that enforces authentication, which then needs to pass along authenticated requests to individual microservices (that check for authorization). I'd like to implement an OAuth2 flow at the API Gateway layer, with the 302 redirect response back to the return URL storing the bearer token in the browser's session storage. The UI can then include the bearer token in subsequent requests with the Authorization header.

What I've ran into though is that the OpenIDConnect flow only allows me to do this with session based cookies. That is not ideal in a stateless microservice implementation, as it requires me to either set user-based affinity to an instance of the API Gateway that contains the session storage in memory, or requires me to delegate session storage to an external session storage (e.g. Redis).

I want to avoid sessions as much as possible, but looking into the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService I have to configure a SignInScheme in my .AddOpenIdConnect() options, and the only thing that implements the IAuthenticationSignInHandler is the CookieAuthenticationHandler

[image]

[image]

How can I get an OAuth2 flow working, ideally with OpenIDConnect, while being able to configure how I return the token back to the user, without having to use cookie-based sessions?

Comment: With OAUTH2 you send two request/response.  The first request is to get the token in the response and the second request is the query where you add the token.  Cookies can be used so you do not have to get a token every time you run the application.  You can use the existing cookie and then send only one request/response.  You do not need to use cookies, but then you have to always send two request/response.

Answer (score 0):

The service instance initiating the OpenID Connect flow, should also be the same that completes the flow.

Regarding the cookies, you can make the session cookie to work across services, by properly configuring the Data Protection API, to use the same encryption key across the services.

See:
[Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

I also blogged about the data protection API here for many years ago:

[Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en)

Comment: Interesting blog post, hadn't read anything about the Data Protection API. I'll have to do some digging and let you know.